# Shinyapp for renaming multiple files

Tags: r, shiny

Hi I'm trying to create a shiny app that will allow renaming of multiple files at once. My question I guess is how do I call a function within the server that changes the names of the files in the directory specified.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Rename Multiuple files"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("input_dir", label = "Choose Input Directory"),
      textInput("search_pattern", label = "Choose a search pattern"),
      textInput("replacement", label = "Choose a replacement pattern"),
      submitButton('Submit')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h4("You're directory"),
      textOutput("directory"),
      textOutput("search_pattern")
    )
  )
)

rename.files = function(input_dir, search_pattern, replacement){

  filez = list.files(input_dir, pattern = search_pattern )
  sapply(filez,FUN=function(eachPath){
    file.rename(from=eachPath,to=sub(pattern = search_pattern,
                                     replacement = replacement,eachPath))})
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$directory = renderText({input$input_dir})
  output$search_pattern = renderText({input$search_pattern})
  output$replacement = renderText({input$replacement})


  reactive(rename.files(input$input_dir,input$search_pattern,input$replacement))

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possibility that can point you in the right direction. Note that I use the `shinyDirPicker` from `shinyFiles` to get a directory from the user.

Hope this helps!

---

[image]

---

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Rename Multiple files"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      shinyDirButton('directory','Select Directory:','Select Directory:'),
      textInput("search_pattern", label = "Choose a search pattern"),
      textInput("replacement", label = "Choose a replacement pattern"),
      actionButton('submit','Submit')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h4("Your directory"),
      textOutput("directory"),
      textOutput("search_pattern")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  shinyDirChoose(input,'directory',roots=c(wd='.'))

  observeEvent(input$submit,{
    directory = parseDirPath(roots = c(wd='.'), input$directory)
    myfiles = list.files(directory)
    new_names = gsub(input$search_pattern,input$replacement,myfiles)
    file.rename(paste0(directory,'/',myfiles),paste0(directory,'/',new_names))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful